# Using C++, get f(n+1)=3/4*f(n)+4 result

Tags: c++, math, recursion, functional-programming

I'm really fresh to C++, and I faced difficulties with the next question :

Write a program that asks the user to enter a number : n 
THEN calculate f(n).

Notice that :

```
       f(0)=3      and      f(n+1) = 3/4 * f(n) + 4 ?
```

For example :

```
       f(1)= 6.25      
       f(2)= 8.69
       f(3)= 10.52 
       f(4)= 11.89
       f(5)= 12.92
```

====================================================

So, how can I solve this?

thanks for all..

I try this code depending on Mr. paxdiablo answer :

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
   double x=0.0;
   cout<<" enter an integer N:";
   cin>> x;

   double f1(double x)
   {
      if x==0.0
          return 3;
      return 3 / 4 * f1 (x-1) + 4;
   }

return 0;
}
```

But the program never runs!

================================================

**The Correct Solution is :**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip> //To enable "setprecision" tool
using namespace std;

double f(int x){
    if (x==0)
       {return 3;}
    return (3.0/4.0) * f(x-1) + 4.0;  //we add zeros to get "double" results
}


int main()
{
   int n=0;
   cout<<" Please, enter an integer :";
   cin>> n;
   cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<f(n); //"setprecision" used to get only two digits after the point

return 0;
}
```

***BIG thanks to everyone gave me a hand and special thank to  Mr. paxdiablo.***

Comment: At which point are you stuck? Show us what you tried so far and what errors you get.

Comment: get "double f1(double x)" part out of the main. and use parentheses to get correct answer

Comment: You output `enter an integer`, but you read it into a double. Also, your function should take an integer as its input argument (it also makes the comparison to zero safer, although it should work with doubles in your special case). Otherwise, apart from some syntax errors (look up `if` and functions in your book), you have almost solve the problem. Just output the result.

Comment: Don't say "why is this code not working."  Print out what the error is and then it is within scope of this site.

Comment: as posted by mhs, you have the f1 function declared in main(). Unless this is some new C++ feature I'm unaware of, I assume you need to move the f1 function declartion outside of main (before main if you don't want to declare a prototype), then have main make a call to the f1 function. Also checking for x == 0.0 could be risky, but since the input is supposed to be an integer and since you subtract 1 from x, then double x should contain exact integer values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for ... Recursion Man!

Simply define a recursive function that returns 3 when n is zero or calls itself with a reduced problem.

Pseudo-code would be something like

```
def f(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 3
    return 3 / 4 * f(n-1) + 4
```

You can use `std::cin >> dv` to get a value from the user and that function (recoded in C++) to do the grunt work. Then `std::cout << result` to output the result. Just remember to use doubles rather than ints, including constants like `3.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the recursive function `f`, then read the input from the user, then apply the function to the input you've read (probably as an integer?), and print the output.